# condition_variable wait on lock

Tags: c++, multithreading

I try to use condition_variable with unique_lock from stl.

But it fails on spin() function. As I can understand it was an interlocking problem. But I can't understand why.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

void spin();

bool stop = false;
bool done = false;

std::thread th(spin);
std::mutex mutex;
std::condition_variable cv;


void join() 
{
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
        stop = true;
    }

    cv.notify_one();

    th.join();
}

void set_done()
{
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);

        std::cout << "setting done" << std::endl;

        done = true;
    }

    cv.notify_one();
}

void spin()
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);

        if (done)
        {
            std::cout << "done..." << std::endl;
            continue;
        }

        if (stop)
        {
            return;
        }

        cv.wait(lock);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    set_done();

    join();

    return 0;
}
```

Code above just wrotes "setting done" and fails with runtime error.

Why did spin's lock fails when set_done unlock the mutex already?

Comment: What is the runtime error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The runtime error happens because you have a race condition between building the mutex and cv and starting the thread. The new thread starts and tries to use mutex before the main thread completed constructing it.

Answer (score 3):

Runtime error could happen because you starting thread during crt startup when some other global variables not initialized. Try to start thread in main function. Not sure that it's your case, because theoretically it should crash in the beginning. But anyway, your implementation is potential crash at least.

You have infinite loop in spin because it permanently falls to statement "if(done) continue". Put "if(stop) return" before "if(done) continue".